# How to make resource test with Multipart feature

Tags: java, jersey, multipartform-data, dropwizard, multipart

I created my resources to handle some images, and I wanted to test them with JUnit's `@ClassRule`, as I did before. They look like this :

```
@Path("/myImage")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response postImage(
       @FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream) {
//doStuff
}
```

Now, I wanted to test it, and I have a problem with it. I fought that this class rule will be ok

```
@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
                .addResource(new MyResource())
                .addResource(new MultiPartBundle())
                .build();
```

But I still get an Error

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>
> [[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public ...

How to write a proper class rule for this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you have not register the `MutliPartFeature` with the server. The `MultiPartBundle` (which registers the `MultiPartFeature`) is not something that is supported with the `ResourceTestRule`. So you just need to register it yourself

```
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
                .addResource(new MyResource())
                .addProvider(MultiPartFeature.class) 
                .build();
```

Same with the client. You will also need to register the feature if you want to use multipart the serialize on the client side

```
resource.client().register(MultiPartFeature.class)..
```

You can see a full example [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1496#issuecomment-202352516)